# iPhone dropped not responding to touch

Tags: iphone

Dropped my iPhone 5 now screen comes on but also has horizontal lines on half the screen and won't respond to my touch . Is it fixable?

Answer (score 1):

Fixable? Yes, but will obviously need a new screen which can cost a pretty penny.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that only the screen itself if broken. If it turns on and lights up then the internals (logic board, battery, memory) would most likely all be working fine.

You can get the screen replaced by any mobile phone repair shop/stall at your local mall, these will be between $50-$100 typically and are 3rd party (not genuine apple) screens.

Apple can also process a repair for the screen using genuine parts, however this is generally a bit more expensive.

A good option would be to go into an Apple retail store if you have one nearby to get a quote